# Paint a themed button using DrawFrameControl?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using DrawFrameControl to paint a button, but it has the Windows 98 look. I want the button to look like whatever the current theme is, though. Can that be achieved using DrawFrameControl, or do I need to use uxtheme.dll directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use it for drawing themed UI elements. Use uxtheme.dll.
See [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/01/445998.aspx)

Comment: The link does not work